External web application: how to construct Appian record url using only record ID
The US Department of Labor (DOL) has an application called "GPMS" that is built using Appian. The application's url is https://cmp.dol.gov/suite/sites/scsep/.
My company builds a related web application. There's duplication between the GPMS (Appian) application and our web application due to a lack of interoperability in GPMS. For example, the GPMS application has "case" records and so does our application. We want to make it easy for a user to navigate from a case in our application to the corresponding case in the GPMS (Appian) application.
The users have entered the GPMS (Appian) "case IDs" (8 digit numbers) into our system. Is there a way to construct a link using only the numeric case ID that would open the corresponding case record in Appian?
For example, let's say there's a case with ID "123456789" in GPMS (Appian). The current url to the page in GPMS is something like the following:
https://cmp.dol.gov/suite/sites/scsep/page/cases/record/{...long encrypted parameter...}/view/summary
                                                        --------------------------------

There's no way for our application to know what the "long encrypted parameter" part of the URL is. Is there an alternative url scheme that accepts a simple record ID? For example, something like:
https://cmp.dol.gov/suite/sites/scsep/page/cases/record/record-by-id/{record-id}/view/summary
                                                                     -----------

I tried asking on the Appian forums and through our GPMS contacts but have not received a response:
https://community.appian.com/discussions/f/integrations/37988/external-web-application-how-to-construct-appian-record-url-using-only-record-id

You would probably need to check their documentation if their API exposes such type of parameter, It is not about the technology rather whether their systems exposes the functionality or not. Looking into the link it does looks like you need to be logged in. So I'm assuming your company is already logged in to it? If so and once you confirm whether their API supports it or not you could build a redirect into your system: https://mysystem.com/mygeneratedId -> maps to the correct link on their systems and redirects to it ?

You have 2 options. If you know the encryption key of the appian application you can replicate the behaviour by generating an encrypted record id, otherwise you have to map each case id of your site with the appian url. Another option could be to debug the appian website to try to intercept a network traffic request that decodes that parameter, and then you could implement an algorithm in your web app.
